# Issue With Reading Json Value

Tags: c#, json

I have an application using the web api in c sharp. I have the following json, and i need to parse the

```
   mobile_synch_tax_r
```

value to test for a condition. The issue is that while this method worked using a windows service, it is not working in the controller of the web api.

The relevant json is:

```
{"SYNC_DATA": {
  "mobile_synch_tax_r": [
    {
      "idtax_registration":66,
      "gender": "",
      "title": "",
      "name": "AK",
      "home_address": "",
      "state_of_origin": "A",
      "home_town": "",
      "local_government": "",
      "occupation": "",
      "company_name": "",
      "office_address": "No",
      "ministry": "",
      "market": "",
      "park": "",
      "phone_number": "",
      "email_address": "",
      "photo_url": "",
      "tax_id": "285",
      "state": null,
      "registered_by": "imported",
      "biometric_status": 0,
      "registration_type": 2,
      "group_id": 100,
      "taxpayer_password": "*6BB",
      "tax_exempt": 0,
      "active": 1,
      "disability": "",
      "rf1": 1,
      "rf2": 1,
      "rf3": 1,
      "rf4": 1,
      "rf5": 1,
      "lf1": 1,
      "lf2": 1,
      "lf3": 1,
      "lf4": 1,
      "lf5": 1,
      "registered_on": "2015",
      "drivers_license_number": "",
      "national_number": "",
      "international_passport_number": "",
      "company_rcc": "",
      "workplace_category": "",
      "office_lg": "",
      "office_city": "n",
      "parent_id": "",
      "workplace_type": 0,
      "marital_status": "",
      "nationality": "u",
      "vend_pin": 0,
      "residential_address_status": "",
      "dob": null,
      "surname": "Ad",
      "first_name": "",
      "middle_name": "",
      "utin": "",
      "last_pw_reset_by": "",
      "temp_reg": 0,
      "company_size": "",
      "business_commencement_date": null,
      "proprietor_tax_id": "",
      "business_ownership_type": "",
      "has_subsidiary": false,
      "subsidiary": false,
      "subsidiary_of": "",
      "n": "",
      "locked": false,
      "author": "",
      "synch_status": false
    }]}}
```

This is the code in the controller:

```
         // POST api/ak
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage value)
    {
       var someText = value.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Library.WriteErrorLog("Data Received" + someText);

        var objects = JObject.Parse(someText);
        Library.WriteErrorLog("Objects are" + objects);
                            if (objects != null)
                            {
                                foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> app in objects)
                                {
                                    var rootName = app.Key;
                                    if (rootName == "mobile_synch_tax_r")

           {"Have your way with me"}}
```

The code is not able to check if the

```
                   rootName=="mobile_synch_tax_r"
```

How am i missing it?

Comment: did you debug it and and watched what are the properties of `objects`?

Comment: Yes i did...the exact same code works in a windows service application. Its just on the web api that it is acting up

Comment: are you parsing the exat JSON you provided? If so, your `objects` properties collection has only one property: "SYNC_DATA", so the condition `rootName == "mobile_synch_tax_r"` will never be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for value of the `"mobile_synch_tax_r"` property, you can use [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to get it:

```
var mobile_synch_tax_r = objects.SelectToken("..mobile_synch_tax_r");
```

`..` is the *recursive descent* operator, so this query searches the JSON object hierarchy for the first property named `"mobile_synch_tax_r"`, and returns its value.